# SharePoint hosted app, update procedure failure

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-addin, app

I deployed a SharePoint hosted App with 4 customs list without content type.
I have a catalog site where I publish my apps.
When I try to update the app, using the standar procedure (change version number, do not change product ID, publish the new version and get it from site content), I get always an error:

> There was a problem accessing the file system on the server

I tried with a simplest app (no lists) and it works fine.
Where the problem can be? 
Any suggestion on how can I debug it?

**UPDATE LOG :**
[Error Logs](http://pastebin.com/css8kbnk)

I think these are the problems:

> Deleting App with fingerprint ZhFIkslOFykRZ8tWw0MOOtGdj3SXTvwzNYtJkUzJVtnU/NVndT0R+hyN7iU2SiHJ/FA6sIQ7j+UYSJ8xCYbtzA== on site 66093b39-e790-4ddd-bfc4-48dbb99844be    1b0e889c-7e4b-90fd-fbf8-4128b477434c
>
> **The App with fingerprint** ZhFIkslOFykRZ8tWw0MOOtGdj3SXTvwzNYtJkUzJVtnU/NVndT0R+hyN7iU2SiHJ/FA6sIQ7j+UYSJ8xCYbtzA== on site 66093b39-e790-4ddd-bfc4-48dbb99844be **was to be deleted, but it did not exist**    1b0e889c-7e4b-90fd-fbf8-4128b477434c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the logging to Verbose and see your ULS log entries,  or login to one of the server and execute merge-splogfile powershell script to get logs from different servers in your farm and specify the start time and end time. (please read more on merge-splogfile command before you use it)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Once you have exact error message,  you will know what is causing issue,  usually a file stuck on your file system,  or fields with same id etc.  these are the common scenarios.

Comment: I used Merge-SPLogFile, I see SPAppManifest: "Parsed manifest has productId d08c9742-0bed-45bd-abc0-77cf271a1df3 version 1.0.0.1 name 'MyAppName'770b889c-fe7b-90fd-fbf8-4edf0ed64beb"
Any suggestion?

Comment: Added Link to logs

Comment: Solved, I had some actions in my solution, old stuff, the problem was there. But thanks for the help on logs ;)

Comment: glad that it worked for You,  these types of errors occurs due to some stuck files :)...